# How can I confirm that iCloud Backup is enabled for my app?

Tags: ios, backup, icloud

I have an iOS app that stores large amounts of data on the device. We rely on iCloud Backup to preserve data in case the user replaces or resets their device.

Unfortunately, users sometimes disable iCloud backup for just our app to save space on iCloud; then, months later, they attempt to restore data onto their new device but there's no app data to restore because they stopped backing it up.

I'd really, really like to be able to find out if the user has iCloud Backup checked for our particular app, so we can give users occasional alerts warning them that their data is not being backed up.

Is there any way to programmatically determine whether my app has the iCloud Backup slider set to ON or OFF?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @SAHM No, but would still like one.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the `ubiquityIdentityToken` property on `NSFileManager` it should be non-nil if iCloud is setup and enabled for your app.

Comment: Isn't this for iCloud document storage / iCloud Drive, rather than iCloud Backup?

Answer (score -1):

You can't. That is because you don't say to iCloud Backup that you want your app to be backed up, it just takes NSUserDefaults and files (not flagged) from DocumentsDirectory and saves them. 
You could better write an Alert to give more information why is so important having this backup on and show her once.

Oh and please bear in mind that storing to iCloud non-user-generated content may lead to reject your app because:

> **Important**: Apps should avoid mingling app data and user data in the
>   same file. Doing so will unnecessarily increase backup sizes and can
>   be considered a violation of the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.

Comment: Yes, I know how iCloud decides which files to back up. The question is about how to read the user setting about whether or not to back my app up. The user can toggle each app on or off in the Settings app.

Comment: And I answered in my first phrase. **You can't**